# Vaadin Change the default Session Expired Notification?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

How to change the default Session Expired Notification; both the message and the type of notification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change session expired message you need to create your own `SystemMessagesProvider`, where you define it. For example in a servlet deployment, you could do the following:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {

    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();

        CustomizedSystemMessages messages = new CustomizedSystemMessages();
        messages.setSessionExpiredCaption("Session expired caption");
        messages.setSessionExpiredMessage("Session expired more detailed message");

        getService().setSystemMessagesProvider(e -> messages);

    }
}
```

There is no a built-in way to change the type of notification. Of course you can style it with css, but the styling affects to other system notifications as well.