# Vaadin system messages in the language of the user

Tags: java, internationalization, vaadin7

As described in the documentation and in ticket [Vaadin Change the default Session Expired Notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634364/vaadin-change-the-default-session-expired-notification), it is possible in Vaadin to override the system messages using the method `getService().setSystemMessagesProvider`.

I'm working on a multilanguage web application and would like to show the "session expired" message in the language of the user`(using AbstractComponent.getLocale()`) but the `servletInitialized` is not within the context of a user session. I know there is a session because it just expired :)

It would be nice if the system messages were defined in standard java resource bundle properties files (like javax.validation does). This way translations could be described using the standard i18n mechanisms of java.

But in the meantime: is there a way to display a system message in the language of the user?

Comment: In the hope to get more response I've created a ticket @Vaadin: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/16790920